# turning off azure media services end-point when idle

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

is it possible to turn off an azure media services end-point when idle, and turn it on again by demand (either by ways of configuration or programmatically?)

the purpose of this being saving costs on the end-point when not used.

Answer (score 0):

There are several billing meters which apply for azure media services See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/media-services/ for all details.

Main price components:

1. Storage - you are paying based on how many space consumed by your assets. You can delete assets which are you no longer planning to use to avoid extra charges.
2. Encoding without reserved units - usage charges based on size of processed data. Your are not paying if system is in idle state.
3. Encoding with reserved Units - Same as #2 plus you are paying for allocation of resources.Reserved units help you to encode multiple jobs in a same time. Use portal to increase/decrease number of reserved units or REST/API, Client SDK to configure this parameter - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/azure/dn859236.aspx#update_EncodingReservedUnitType
4. Live channels - For all live channel types, billing is based on the amount of time the channel is in running state and not based on the incoming and processed data. You can stop or delete channel to avoid incurring charges. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783458.aspx#stop_channels
5. Streaming units  - Provides dedicated bandwidth capacity for both on-demand and live streaming. Pricing per unit. You can start/stop/scale streaming endpoint through portal or rest api - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn783468.aspx
6. Content Protection - charges based on licences/keys issued through a service.

Comment: good points - i will use the Streaming end points api (point 5) to control the up time of the streaming units.